# What is the right way to debug in iPython notebook?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, ipython, pdb

As I know, `%debug magic` can do debug within one cell.

However, I have function calls across multiple cells.

For example,

```
In[1]: def fun1(a)
           def fun2(b)
               # I want to set a breakpoint for the following line #
               return do_some_thing_about(b)

       return fun2(a)

In[2]: import multiprocessing as mp
       pool=mp.Pool(processes=2)
       results=pool.map(fun1, 1.0)
       pool.close()
       pool.join
```

What I tried:

1. I tried to set `%debug` in the first line of cell-1. But it enter into debug mode immediately, even before executing cell-2.
2. I tried to add `%debug` in the line right before the code `return do_some_thing_about(b)`. But then the code runs forever, never stops.

What is the right way to set a break point within the ipython notebook?

Comment: too bad answering "don't use Jupyter notebook" doesn't count as an answer

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use **ipdb**

Install it via

```
pip install ipdb
```

Usage:

```
In[1]: def fun1(a):
   def fun2(a):
       import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() # debugging starts here
       return do_some_thing_about(b)
   return fun2(a)
In[2]: fun1(1)
```

For executing line by line use <kbd>n</kbd> and for step into a function use <kbd>s</kbd> and to exit from debugging prompt use <kbd>c</kbd>.

For complete list of available commands: https://appletree.or.kr/quick_reference_cards/Python/Python%20Debugger%20Cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: ipdb does't give me the debug prompt in the other cell with the sample code mentioned in the question. Now the code keeps running forever.

Comment: @Rex For me it works. Where did you put ipdb?
Put import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(); before the line return do_some_thing_about(b). Then, call fun1(a) from second cell, it should work. For exiting the debugging promt use 'c'

Comment: @Rex Updated the answer for more clarity.

Comment: This works in iPython console but not in iPython notebook (which is what the question asked).  When I type `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` within a notebook cell it says `MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of TerminalIPythonApp are being created.`

Comment: new to jupyter...it seems that it is more suitable for presentation and sharing code snippets...can we have functionality that IDEs (like eclipse, rstudio) provide like actual debugging, step through, breakpoints, adding watch to the expression and variables etc. At first, it seems that it is not the case, just want to be sure.....

Comment: Very weird for me. Seems to work sometimes but not everytime. And if you forget to quit properly the debugger, you can stay blocked in it and be forced to restart the kernel. Definitely not an ideal solution...

Answer (score 110):

You can use `ipdb` inside jupyter with:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer; Tracer()()
```

---

**Edit**: the functions above are deprecated since IPython 5.1. This is the new approach:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
```

Add `set_trace()` where you need a breakpoint. Type `help` for `ipdb` commands when the input field appears.

Comment: `Tracer` was depreciated. Now it works this way: `from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace` and `set_trace()` evokes a breakpoint. Source: https://davidhamann.de/2017/04/22/debugging-jupyter-notebooks/

Comment: Handy to use as one line, wherever needed: `from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace;set_trace()`

Answer (score 25):

In Python 3.7 you can use [breakpoint()](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-553-built-in-breakpoint) function. Just enter

```
breakpoint()
```

wherever you would like runtime to stop and from there you can use the same pdb commands (r, c, n, ...) or evaluate your variables.

Comment: To add to this, when you call breakpoint(), you can type 'help' in the text box that appears to get a list of commands.

Comment: There seems to be a persistent issue of hang-up after using breakpoint() or pdb: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10516

Answer (score 19):

Your return function is in line of def function(main function), you must give one tab to it.
And Use

```
%%debug
```

instead of

```
%debug
```

to debug the whole cell not only line. Hope, maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 13):

You can always add this in any cell:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and the debugger will stop on that line.  For example:

```
In[1]: def fun1(a):
           def fun2(a):
               import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # debugging starts here
           return fun2(a)

In[2]: fun1(1)
```

Comment: @Rex Not necessarily. [`ipdb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) is a refactor of the Python Debugger that is more closely integrated with IPython. [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) is built in.

Comment: `ipdb` can also be used outside the ipython shell and comes with some conveniences like tab completion.

Answer (score 13):

After you get an error, in the next cell just run `%debug` and that's it.

Comment: that is awesome!

Comment: however, this must wait for the exception to occur, we might want to test what is the variable in the runtime by setting some breakpoint

Comment: by _far_ the most practical way to debug long-running code

Comment: Can you elaborate and explain what it does exactly?

Comment: will open a debugger below the cell. If you need help on that debuggger, just type 'h'

Answer (score 9):

The [`%pdb` magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-pdb) is good to use as well. Just say `%pdb on` and subsequently the `pdb` debugger will run on all exceptions, no matter how deep in the call stack. Very handy.

If you have a particular line that you want to debug, just raise an exception there (often you already are!) or use the `%debug` magic command that other folks have been suggesting.

Answer (score 8):

Just type `import pdb` in jupyter notebook, and then use this [cheatsheet](https://focojoaco.blogspot.com/2015/12/python-ipdb-cheatsheet.html) to debug. It's very convenient.

`c` --> continue, `s` --> step, `b 12` --> set break point at line 12 and so on.

> Some useful links:
> [Python Official Document on pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), [Python pdb debugger examples for better understanding how to use the debugger commands](https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/).

> Some useful screenshots:
> [image][image]

Comment: Good answer. However, I think (I am new to Jupyter notebook) one should add %debug to set a breakpoint.

Comment: What I do is copy and paste `pdb.set_trace()` to where I want to set a breakpoint, since the `b line_no` is not working in Jupyter Notebook and works well on python IDLE.

Comment: Thanks! I also uploaded some screenshots that I tested today. If I could switch over to Python IDLE I would love to do so..

Comment: Also, I find a way to show line number on jupyter notebook, click new line, and then press l.Of course you can also program your own shortcut, links are available on the jupyter notebook website.

Comment: I use always "p" to show the list of commands in the Jupyter notebook. When I write "show line numbers", the command appears there witt the shortcut next to it. You can also learn the shortcut of the command, which you want to use.

Answer (score 6):

I just discovered [PixieDebugger](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/07/pixie-debugger-python-debugging-tool-jupyter-notebooks-data-scientist-must-use/). Even thought I have not yet had the time to test it, it really seems the most similar way to debug the way we're used in ipython with ipdb

[image]

It also has an "evaluate"  tab

Answer (score 3):

A native debugger is being made available as an extension to JupyterLab. Released a few weeks ago, this can be installed by getting the relevant extension, as well as xeus-python kernel (which notably comes without the magics well-known to ipykernel users):

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/debugger
conda install xeus-python -c conda-forge
```

This enables a visual debugging experience well-known from other IDEs.

[image]

Source: [A visual debugger for Jupyter](https://blog.jupyter.org/a-visual-debugger-for-jupyter-914e61716559)

Comment: xeus-python doesn't run on my Windows 10. Check my issue [xeus-python issue on github](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-python/issues/239#issuecomment-606737348)

Answer (score 0):

In VsCode

File -> Preferances -> Settings ->
Open Settings (JSON) [small page icon on the upper right]

Paste this line of code to the end of it

```
"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true
```

Now you should see debug option at the top navigation bar

[image]