# Is it possible to split a Jupyter cell across cells when it contains a function, loop, or other block?

Tags: python, julia, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter has a feature in being able to execute one cell at a time.  If a cell has a lot of statements it's often possible (desirable) to split it into smaller single statement cells, except when a block is involved,e.g if, for, def, etc.

this question was asked earlier in a different way:

[Execute algorithm step by step in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334589/execute-algorithm-step-by-step-in-jupyter)

and answered

[What is the right way to debug in iPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409629/what-is-the-right-way-to-debug-in-ipython-notebook)

While invoking a debugger may be the best option available, it does seem kludgy, and it likely would not work with non Python kernels.

What would be ideal is to have nested cells, and have a way to execute the entire block or the subcell.

for a Python example splitting a cell containing:

```
if 0 == 1:
    zero = 1
else:
    zero = 0
```

into, say, two cells:

```
if 0 == 1:
    zero = 1
```

and

```
else:
    zero = 0
```

likewise for Julia or R.

a debugger solution would not be my preference.

Comment: There is a keyboard shortcut to split a cell

Comment: yes, thx.  i was already aware of how to split cells (cnt-shft-minus on macs)  it unfortunately doesn't work well on code which is in a block.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in a block. It splits the cell at the line of the cursor

Comment: Okay, but cells execute in whole. That else statement will cause a syntax error

Comment: i've edited the Q showing an if else.  similar situations for functions and loops.  splitting

Comment: yes. that's the point.  i want to modify cell execution behaviour, so it would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The reason for this is that the else condition by itself would cause an error. You can split the cell using control+shift+subtract but once you try and run the last cell an error occurs. You can see the exact example of this in the picture I have included. Please let me know if you have any further questions/comments!

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ9U9.png)

Comment: Well, the point of my question was the difficulty of doing so.  All you've done is to show that splitting into top level cells doesn't work, which was already obvious.  What I am looking for is a way to create subcells.

Comment: ShpielMeister - this feature would be great if exist