# How to PySpark Codes in Debug Jupyter Notebook

Tags: debugging, pyspark

I am wondering I can debug pyspark codes in Jpyter notebook? I have tried the solution for regular python codes in Jupyter using ipdb module.

[What is the right way to debug in iPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409629/what-is-the-right-way-to-debug-in-ipython-notebook)

But it is not working in with notebook with pyspark kernel..

Please note that: My question is about debugging pyspark within Jupypter notebook and not in ItelliJ IDE or any other python IDEs.

background:

- I am on MacOS yosemite.
- My spark version is 1.6.2
- Jupyter kernel is:Apache Toree PySpark
- I have ipdb installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Jyupter notebook if you want to play around and debug PySpark code, once Spark is installed and set up (good guide to show you how here: https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f) you can import SparkSession and create a local instance:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("pyspark-test").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("test.csv", header=True)
```