# Debugging pyspark in ipdb-fashion

Tags: python, debugging, pyspark, ipdb

When developing python code, I make use of the package `ipdb`.

This halts the execution of the python code there, where I have inserted `ipdb.set_trace()`, and presents me with a python interpreter command line.

However, in the python code that I develop for pyspark, and which I send off using `spark-submit`, the `ipdb` package does not work.

So my question is: is there a way, in which I can debug my pyspark code in a manner similar to using the `ipdb` package?

Note: Obviously, for python code executed on remote nodes, this would not be possible. But when using `spark-submit` with option `--master local[1]` I have hopes that it might be possible.

PS. There is a related question, but with a narrower scope, here: [How to PySpark Codes in Debug Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780112/how-to-pyspark-codes-in-debug-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark

      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
      /_/

Using Python version 3.7.1 (default, Jun 16 2019 23:56:28)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

In [1]: sc.stop()

In [2]: run -d main.py
Breakpoint 1 at /Users/andrii/work/demo/main.py:1
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
> /Users/andrii/work/demo/main.py(1)<module>()
1---> 1 print(123)
      2 import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
      3 a = 2
      4 b = 3
```

or

```
In [3]: run main.py
123
> /Users/andrii/work/demo/main.py(3)<module>()
      2 import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
----> 3 a = 2
      4 b = 3
```