# How to add a breakpoint in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter notebook, if I have

```
print("hello")
quit()
```

in the first cell  and

```
print("Good bye")
```

in the second, when I do "Run all" it prints `hello` and also `Good bye`.

In other words, `quit()` seems to only stop the execution of the cell itself, not the whole script.

Is there some way to add a breakpoint to your code so that it stops executing when it gets to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the right way to debug in iPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409629/what-is-the-right-way-to-debug-in-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 38):

You can use [`IPython.core.debugger.Pdb`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.debugger.html#IPython.core.debugger.Pdb) to invoke [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Insert the following line to set a breakpoint.

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb; Pdb().set_trace()
```

See [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) for debugger commands.

Also, you can use [`%debug`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-debug) magic to invoke pdb after an error. Just type `%debug` to the next cell if an exception occurs. Then pdb runs from its stack frames.

Answer (score 16):

From the JupyterLab docs:

> JupyterLab 3.0 now ships with a Debugger front-end by default.
>
> For the debugger to be enabled and visible, a kernel with support for
> debugging is required.

If you are using Pip, install the Xeus-Python kernel with `pip install xeus-python`.

Then open a  jupyterlab notebook, and choose the new kernel from the toolbar:

[image: Selecting Kernel]

You can then debug your code as follows:

[image: Debugging in JupyterLab]

Source: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html

Comment: This looks exciting!

Comment: Note for self, instead of running jupyter notebook, run jupyter-lab. this is a different interface and allows debugging. The old one does not.

Comment: Great news. Any recommended kernal for Conda?

Comment: I think `xeus-python` is also available in Conda. Try: `conda install -c conda-forge xeus-python`

Comment: Now you do not need any special kernel but you have to enable the debugger using the bug icon (on the right side of the notebook's top bar). I am using the debugger in JupyterLab 3.4, Python 3.10.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know, jupyter notebook doesn't have a breakpoint function however you can add something like:

```
assert False, "breakpoint"
```

where you want to stop although it isn't very elegant.

Comment: I simply use 0/0 which throws a ZeroDivisionError and stops the execution

Comment: @Akronix that would be simple to use, but confusing for anyone who may look into your code, his answer is descriptive

Answer (score 4):

- Ensure that you have selected the kernel (e.g., Python 3) on the upper right corner of the coding window
- Select the debugging icon on its left (as you select it, each line will be numbered)
- Now you can select breakpoints, by clicking on the line number.

Comment: Any recommended kernal for Conda?

Answer (score 3):

Jupyter Notebook has visual debugger just like Jupyter Lab since version 7.0.0, released in July 2023. You can use it exactly like abrac showed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67264599/10266970). Just make sure that you enabled the debugger by clicking on the small bug icon on top right corner and optionally display the debugger panel (with Ctrl + Shift + E shortcut or using top bar: `View > Debugger Panel`).

Answer (score -7):

You can probably try `exit()` but I am not sure if that's exactly what you need.

Comment: That does exactly the same as using `quit()` as far as I can tell. In other words it doesn't stop the rest of the script from running.