# Python IDEs with Full Debugging Support

Tags: python, ipython, data-science, conda

I have Anaconda installed in my system and personally use jupyter notebook for my development. The problem is I want to debug my code with a visual debugger which jupyter doesn't support [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409629/what-is-the-right-way-to-debug-in-ipython-notebook).

Could you introduce some tool which gives full visual debugging experience and also works well with Anaconda?

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120586/4201765) seems appropriate to me but as mentioned in the comments, It's problematic in windows 10.

Comment: This is likely off-topic, please see [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks. I think you mean rule number 4 but my question not particularly subjective. I just need a visual debugger and any tool that works would be sufficient.  @AMC

Comment: I think that rule still applies, I'm not sure how it can be _not particularly subjective_.

Comment: Maybe we are not in the same page. Could you please recommend an stackexchange site that is on-topic for this question?! @AMC

Comment: You might want to look at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com - this question might be on-topic there. Definitely off-topic for Stack Overflow though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I'm using it myself with anaconda and [python interactive](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) files, plus full debugging experience is available. In my opinion, it's the best IDE for DS with python (see [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/data-science-tutorial)).

Comment: Have you also encountered performance problems? I used it once for debugging which was extremely slow.